# How to disable and enable input type on function execution?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have the following code.

html:

```
<div ng-controller="Test">
        <input type="text" class="message-input" id="testId" placeholder="Enter message" ng-model="textMessage" ng-disabled="isDisabled" autofocus />
        <br><br>
      <button type="submit" value="Submit" ng-click="enteredMessage(textMessage)">Submit</button>
     </div>
```

js:

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);
app.controller('Test',function($scope){
$scope.isDisabled = false;
    $scope.enteredMessage = function(msg){
    alert("Entered Message is: "+msg);
   console.log("your input should be in diabled mode now");
   $scope.isDisabled = true;
   console.log("your input should be in enabled mode now with auto-focused");
    }
});
```

If I execute this, I can able to get auto-focused by default to enter some text, it is fine.

Means I want to `disable` my `input` type on `ng-click` function executing and then it should be `enabled` after function execution is done with auto-focused to enter the text.

Please let me know that where I am doing wrong and how to do this and Thanks in advance ! Created [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mavdhana/4yfjnby6/2/).

Comment: i can't understand what is your problem. do you want to disable your input when enteredMessage function starts and to reenable it when enteredMessage function ends?

Comment: When you alert, alert prevents the user from accessing any other part of the UI so in part - your input is already "disabled" while the alert is open and "enabled" when the alert closes. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert

Comment: @firegloves, yes ... and while re-enabling input should be like auto focused also (instead of clicking manually input to enter the text, if it is auto-focused means we can directly enter the text ?)

Comment: autofocus attribute is not going to bring back the focus.....

Answer (score 0):

Actually the alert() not has a callback to execute when user click ok button or close it. You need to use some modal or other kind of directive wich support callback, instead, the example below, just disable when alert is show, and enable when click ok. Check it out.

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);

app.controller('Test',function($scope){
$scope.isDisabled = false;
    $scope.enteredMessage = function(msg){
    $scope.isDisabled = true;
    alert("Entered Message is: "+msg);
    console.log("your input should be in diabled mode now");

    //$scope.msg="";
     console.log("your input should be in enabled mode now with autofocus");
     $scope.isDisabled = false;
 }

});
```

I suggest to use **ui.bootstrap** modal or **ngSweetAlert.**

**UPDATE** with function call instead alert. [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/d389yfzt/)

```
  var app = angular.module('app',[]);

    app.controller('Test',function($scope, $window){
    $scope.isDisabled = false;
        $scope.enteredMessage = function(msg){
        $scope.isDisabled = true;
        alert("Entered Message is: "+msg);
        console.log("your input should be in diabled mode now");
        $scope.showConfirm();
        //$scope.msg="";
         //console.log("your input should be in enabled mode now with autofocus");
         //$scope.isDisabled = false;
      }

      $scope.showConfirm = function(){
          if(confirm('your input should be in enabled mode now with autofocus if click Ok')){
             $scope.isDisabled = false;
             var inputBox = $window.document.getElementById('testId');
        inputBox.focus();
          }
      }

    });
```

Comment: I cannot see any new change in your code. Actually it can be any angular function, not alert message or any. I just have written some function to display alert messages. MY requirement should be on input type for any angular function execution. Edited the post.

Comment: the difference is i add a `$scope.isDisabled = true` on top and `$scope.isDisabled= false` on the bottom.

Comment: if your intention is alert to be  some function... yo need first disable the input an when the funciton or primse ends to execute, enable again. thats why are in that order.

Comment: yes, my intention is some function. But it should be enabled with auto-focused and disabled on function executing and then enabled after execution is done with auto-focused to enter the text.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in a comment, [Alert](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert) **already** disabled your UI so putting the input in disabled mode is not useful. For your second issue, to refocus on the input after the alert disappears you can do something like the following

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('Test', function($scope, $window) {
  $scope.enteredMessage = function(msg) {
    alert("Entered Message is: " + msg);
    var inputBox = $window.document.getElementById('testId');
    inputBox.focus();
    console.log("your input should now be in focus");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use time out functionality, to again enable the input element

Example :

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);

app.controller('Test',function($scope,$timeout){
   $scope.isDisabled = false;
   $scope.enteredMessage = function(msg){
   $scope.isDisabled = true;
   alert("Entered Message is: "+msg);
   console.log("your input should be in diabled mode now");

    //5 seconds delay
    $timeout( function(){
        $scope.isDisabled = false;
       },5000);
    console.log("your input should be in enabled mode now with autofocus");
}

});
```

Comment: yes it is fine, but it is not in auto-focused mode after enabled or timeout.